# Deleting albums from Gallery

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, gallery, picasa, google-plus-photos

I have an album called "23 Jan 2012", seems like it was empty when google picasa moved their data to google plus photos, and the thing is - there is no "delete" in the menu if I select it on the phone.

And there is no such an album in the google+ photos.

Any ideas?

Comment: There might be a directory by that name, e.g. in the `DCIM` folder of your SDCard (or one of the other default picture locations). You can check that with a file explorer.

Comment: @Izzy: I did, there is no such :-( All answers I've found refer to deleting it right in Picasa Web, but it's not available anymore

Comment: As the media scanner should re-fill it on its next run: Maybe you simply delete all data from the corresponding apps (via *Settings->Apps->Manage Apps*)? That should kick it. `com.android.providers.media` is the one holding the data, which might turn app in apps as "MediaStorage" or similar.

Comment: @Izzy: it kicks it but returns on next sync. I've found an app that solved my issue - see the answer and thanks

Comment: Ah! I see: so it was not the local gallery, but Picasa. I couldn't see that as I don't use "the cloud" for all my personal stuff :) Glad the issue solved, and thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this issue after a lot of searching.

The normal Picasa page takes you to Google+, and it does not show the empty folders etc.

You have to use Picasa mobile:
https://picasaweb.google.com/m

Log in, and you can delete whatever you want.

Comment: Note that after deleting these from picasaweb you still need to use the `Refresh` option from the menu to re-sync.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool in the play store that can manage Picasa contents: [Perfect Tool for Picasa](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=larry.zou.colorfullife).

And I could delete the extra directories using it.